# Perform a transfer function $\displaystyle H(s)=\frac{y(s)}{u(s)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was given this transfer function in a college exam.

> y(t) is the output variable and u(t) is the input variable):
> $$2\cdot\frac{d^4y(t)}{dt^3}+4 \cdot \frac{d^2y(t)}{dt^2}+6 \cdot y(t)=$$$$2 \cdot \frac{d^2u(t)}{dt^2}+8u(t)$$

Edit: After seeing Vedant's comment, let's assume powers are a typo.

**After long division I've got this:
$ \frac {y(s)}{u(s)}= s^2-2+ \frac {11}{s^2+4} $**

How do I separate it in **$y(s)$** and **$u(s)$**?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Thats a typo, it should be $\frac{d^4y(t)}{dt^4}$

Comment: You have obtained the expression for the transfer function, what you want it from now?